# Python None if check fails

Tags: python-2.7

```
def myFunc( str ):
      print "str=", str
      if str == None:
        print "str is None"
      else:
        print "str is not None, value is:", str
```

This function is called multiple times in my app with str being None. However sometimes, although str is None, the test fails and it prints:

```
str=None
str is not None, value is None
```

How can this happen ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The string `'None'` and the bytestring `b'None'` will both print out None, but not actually be none. Also, you can have custom classes which override their `__str__` methods to return `'None'`, although they're actually not None.

Some aesthetic notes: Python guarantees that there'll only ever be one instance of `None`, so you should use `is` instead of `==`. Also, you should not name your variable `str`, as that's the name of a built-in.

Try this definition:

```
def myFunc(s):
    if s is None:
        print('str is None')
    else:
        print('str is not None, it is %r of type %s' % (s, type(s).__name__))
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped. It prints "str is not None, it is u'None' of type unicode". Which is different from the other cases where the if check works: "str is not None, it is None of type NoneType". So the question is what is u'None' and how can I check against that.

Comment: @Paul don't know if you've had this answered since, but for all the folks coming to this page later: `u'None'` is just a unicode string with value 'None' (`u'None' == 'None'` --> `True`; `u'None' is 'None'` --> `False`). So if you want to check for u'None', you could check for : `if mystr is None or str(mystr) == 'None'`

Answer (score 2):

Check the value of `str` again. If your test fails then `str` is not the special `None` object. Presumably str is in fact the string `'None'`.

```
>>> str = None
>>> str == None
True
>>> str = 'None'
>>> str == None
False
>>> print str
None
```

Judging from your comments, `str` is actually `u'None'` which is a string of type `unicode`. You can test for that like this:

```
>>> s = unicode('None')
>>> s
u'None'
>>> print s
None
>>> s == 'None'
True
```

Now, whilst you could do that, I suspect that your problem lies elsewhere. The calling code must be converting this object to a string, for example with `unicode(None)`. It would most likely be better is the calling code only converted to string if the object is not `None`.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that `str` is bound to the string object `"None"` by any chance?

I would recommend using `if str is None` instead of `==`.  Not to mention, you really shouldn't be using `str` as a variable name.

Comment: Thx. I have renamed my var. to str for stackoverflow example only.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `__repr__` method to show the value:

```
>>> x = None
>>> print 'the value of x is', x.__repr__()
the value of x is None
>>> x = "None"
>>> print 'the value of x is', x.__repr__()
the value of x is 'None'
```